# SQL Syntax JOIN google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am getting this error in Google BigQuery:

```
Error: Ambiguous field reference in SELECT clause. (Remember to fully qualify all field names in the SELECT clause as <table.field>.)
```

My query is

```
SELECT LoanPerf1.loankey, Loans.Key
FROM   prosperloans1.LoanPerf1
JOIN   prosperloans1.Loans
       ON LoanPerf1.loankey = Loans.Key
```

`prosperloans1` is the dataset id
the 2 table names are correct.
the error returns regardless of which field name appears first in the select clause.

The documentation on Google SQL Syntax says this is correct:

```
// Simple JOIN of two tables
SELECT table1.id, table2.username
FROM   table1
JOIN   table2
       ON table1.name = table2.name AND table1.id = table2.customer_id;
```

Thanks
Shawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an AS clause to the table names:

`SELECT LoanPerf1.loankey, Loans.Key 
 FROM prosperloans1.LoanPerf1 as LoanPerf1 
   JOIN prosperloans1.Loans as Loans 
   ON LoanPerf1.loankey = Loans.Key`

Comment: I found this worked: SELECT perf.status, loan.loankey 
FROM   prosperloans1.LoanPerf1 AS perf
JOIN   prosperloans1.loansfinalstatus2 AS loan
       ON perf.loankey = loan.loankey;     so it is either the AS you mentioned or having fields in the ON statement have matching field names.